# Import module from specific folder

Tags: python

I have a folder called `Script` and inside I have `temp.py` script. My temp script imports module from sub-folder called `lib`.

Lib folder has inside empty `__init__.py` and my `parent_computer_test.py` script.

in my `temp.py` script is the following code:

```
import lib.parent_computer_test as parent_computer_test
parent_computer_test.mainChunk()
parent_computer_test.splitChunks()
```

I managed to import module from sub-folder without any bigger problems.

This workflow/script works fine, **BUT** for a specific reason, my `lib` folder has to be somewhere else on my computer. There is a long story why, but it has to be that way.

Long story short. I want that my `temp.py` from the `/Script` folder imports modules from folder `lib` (or any other name) with `parent_computer_test.py`, but at the same time this folder is no sub-folder of `/Script` - so it is somewhere else in the computer. It can be `C:/development/...` or something.

So my question is how to import a module from a specific folder?

Comment: 1>>>>>>>>import os, sys
2>>>>>>>>lib_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..', '..', '..', 'lib'))
3>>>>>>>>sys.path.append(lib_path)
4>>>>>>>import mymodule

Comment: Duplicate Question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/import-a-module-from-a-relative-path

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7)

Comment: @Virbhadrasinh: This is no duplicate, as the OP does _not_ want to import from a relative path.

Comment: @luator but also in this Question answers are as you relevant

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Append the path to lib folder to the SYS PATH Environment Variable. Then it can be imported from anywhere

```
import os, sys
lib_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..', '..', '..', 'lib'))
sys.path.append(lib_path)
import mymodule
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import imp
yourModule = imp.load_source('yourModuleName', '/path/to/yourModule.py')
foo = yourModule.YourFunction("You", "get", "the", "idea.")
```

I realize this is a special case, but in general, I would avoid stuff like this. Things can get ugly when you use absolute paths, especially if you move things around, and I would only use this for throwaway scripts or on systems that aren't going to change very much.

EDIT: Aswin's answer is a much better longterm solution.

Comment: Thank you! It works like a charm. I know, that this is not the best practise, but as said before... in this case, this is the only scenario.

Comment: Glad to help. Just making sure you realized the risks.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I am complete beginner, so and additional informations are always welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use sys.path.append("path") . But use this just one time. Then try 
import "my_module". IT should be fine.
If you want to remove the path appended you can use,
sys.path.remove("path").